# Overflow issues on Chrome+Retina and Safari in OS X

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, safari, retina-display

I have a website with a two-level sidebar menu. Main menu element is on the left side (`top: 0`, `left: 0`) of the screen. Sub menu element is a child of the main one, positioned right next to it (`top: 0`, `left: 200px`). They both have `position: fixed`, `height: 100%` and `width: 200px`.

I set `overflow-y: auto` on both elements, so that when they are too big for the window size, they become vertically scrollable.

This seems to cause a strange issue in some cases (Chrome only on Retina display, Safari on all displays). The main menu element behaves like it would have `overflow-x: hidden` and because it has fixed width, the child element (submenu) is invisible. Explicitly setting `overflow-x: visible` doesn't help.

[Here's a simple codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jERXrE) that demonstrates the issue. You should see two columns, red and blue, next to eachother. If you have a browser that has the issue, you only see the left one, but the issue is gone as soon as you remove `overflow-y: auto`.